# Is it correct to manipulate state via props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React is it correct to manipulate state in a parent element by manipulating props in a child element (example)? Or is the correct way to return an object and explicitly setState?

Example below just to show where I'm manipulating variable:

```
const Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    person: {name: 'john', age: 47},
  },
  render: function() {
    <div>
      <Child person = {this.state.person} />
    </div>
  }
});

const Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let person = this.props.person;
    person = {name: 'john doe', age:30};
    return(<div> Person {person} </div>);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where in this example are you manipulating state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should take the state of your 'Parent' class and pass it in as props to your 'Child' class.

Your example is correct, except I am not sure why you want to do

```
person = {...}
```

again in the Child's render class.

Maybe you meant

```
const Child = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      let person = this.props.person;
      return(<div> Person {person} </div>);
   }
});
```

This is in docs:  *...props are immutable: they are passed from the parent and are "owned" by the parent.*